# Which REST API status code to return among an empty GET response, when the filter is used

Tags: php, rest, http-headers

In order to understand my question please take a look at the next situation:

**GET api.url.com/cars**  return 200 with a collection of blue and green cars

**GET api.url.com/cars?color=red**  return 204 with no data in body because I don't have red cars in database

Should I return 200 with an empty object instead of 204? If yes, why ? I want an explanation and if possible a source. Thanks!

Comment: Personally, I'd use a 200 and an empty set, because the requestor has made a valid query and expects a valid response... the empty set tells it that there were no valid cars, and to handle it accordingly (ie post a message to that effect) whereas a 204 response tells it to stay on the same page, as though nothing has happened

Comment: @MarkBaker thank you. It's a good point.

Comment: @MarkBaker Please put your comment as an answer so I can close this question. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkBaker Hi. Please post your comment as an answer, so I can upvote id and close this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd use a 200 and an empty set, because the requestor has made a valid query and expects a valid response... the empty set tells it that there were no valid cars, and to handle it accordingly (ie post a message to that effect) whereas a 204 response tells it to stay on the same page, as though nothing has happened